# can't use public access modifier

Tags: c#, syntax-error

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, but I am messing around and fiddling with what I am learning from YouTube beginner tutorials and I'm kind of lost here. can anyone let me know why using the `public` access specifier before the `fields` break everything?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Methods
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            public int _first, _second, _third, _fourth, _fifth;


        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}st number:", i);
                Console.ReadLine();
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        _first = i;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
```

[image: using Public]
[image: Not Using Public]

Comment: Because you can´t declare a field within a method. Without the access-modifier it´s not a field, but a local variable. The same would happen, if you´d apply any other access-modifier, e.g. `private`.

Comment: If you need the variable to be public you need to declare it outside of a function. In your case it would be outside the Main function, in the class it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope.

The fields (inside functions or methods it's better use variable) in the scope of a function cannot be "public" or "protected" or... No, are private to the container scope, and, of course, doesn't need access word.

If you make a field outside the function you can make it public, private, internal... etc...

You cannot make fields out of object or structs.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public int _secondThing // baaaad

    class Methods
    {

        public static int _thing; //good
        int _thing; //good, it's private;
        private int _thing; //good, it's the same
        public int _firstThing; //good

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            public int _first, _second, _third, _fourth, _fifth; //baaad
            int _first, _second; //good
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did this the first time, I initialised the fields outside the method but then I wasn't able to use them as variables inside my main method's switch case statements. 
[link] https://imgur.com/a/P1l3k26

Comment: @ALapper and how do you pretend use non STATIC fields in a STATIC method? You have to make the fields static.

Comment: `_thing` is also bad, as you can´t declare members within namespaces. Your edit is pointless.

Comment: @HimBromBeere sorry, bad editing, StackOverflow, improve your editor!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As DrkDeveloper mentioned it´s a question of the scope of your variables. Depending on where you define a variable it only exists within that specific scope and all of its child-scopes, but not in parent-scopes. So defining somethin at class-level makes it accessable in the entire class, this is in all of its members. Defining a variable within a member such as a method on the other hand makes that variable existing only in that specific scope - in that method. You can´t access it from anywhere outside its scope.

Your first code without the access-modifier works, because the variables are defined within that method - we call them **local variables**. The second code with the access-modifiers would turn those variables into *members* (fields in this case) of the *class*. So you´d define a member in a method that should have a class-scope. This of course does not work.

So you either leave your variables local, or make them `public static` **within your class**.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Methods
    {
        public int _first, _second, _third, _fourth, _fifth;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}st number:", i);
                Console.ReadLine();
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        _first = i;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```